# Add dynamic tiered fee based on cart total in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // The percetage
    $value = 12; // 15%
    // The cart total
    $cart_total = $cart_object->cart_contents_total; 

    // The conditional Calculation
    $fee = $cart_total >= 25 ? $cart_total * $value / 100 : 0;

    if ( $fee != 0 ) 
        $cart_object->add_fee( __( "Kosten MandaBai", "woocommerce" ), $fee, false );
}
```

Comment: I tried the code above and it works very good, but i need something which is based on total cart price not "percentage" of the total cart.

for example:  

total cart is between: 0 - 49,99 fee must be = 8
total cart is between: 50 - 99.99 fee must be = 10
total cart above 100 fee must be = 12

Comment: You can check using $min and $max  like check $cart_total <=49.99 then add your fees same way for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'tiered_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function tiered_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    $total = $cart->cart_contents_total; // The cart total

    if( $total < 50 )
        $fee = 8;
    elseif( $total >= 50 && $total < 100 )
        $fee = 10;
    else
        $fee = 12;

    if ( $fee != 0 ) 
        $cart->add_fee( __( "Kosten MandaBai", "woocommerce" ), -$fee, false );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.